# How to read a specific row of a csv file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have searched like crazy trying to find specifically how to read a row in a csv file.

I need to read a random row out of 1000, each of which has 3 columns. The first column has an email. I need to put in a random email, and get columns 2 and 3 out. (Python 2.7, csv file)

Example:

```
Name Date  Color
Ray  May   Gray
Alex Apr   Green
Ann  Jun   Blue
Kev  Mar   Gold
Rob  May   Black
```

Instead of column 1 row 3, I need [Ann], her whole row. This is a CSV file, with over 1000 names. I have to put in her name and output her whole row.

---

What I have tried

```
from collections import namedtuple
Entry = namedtuple('Entry', 'Name, Date, Color')
file_location = "C:/Users/abriman/Desktop/Book.csv"
ss_dict = {}
spreadsheet = file_location = "C:/Users/abriman/Desktop/Book.csv"
for row in spreadsheet:
    entry = Entry(*tuple(row))
    ss_dict['Ann']
```

And my error reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I have tried other ways too and got little to no result. I'm a beginner at python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your problem could be simple dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> Entry = namedtuple('Entry', 'Name, Date, Color')
>>> [l for l in open('t.tsv', 'r')]
<<<
['Name Date  Color\n',
 'Ray  May   Gray\n',
 'Alex Apr   Green\n',
 'Ann  Jun   Blue\n',
 'Kev  Mar   Gold\n',
 'Rob  May   Black\n']
>>> [l.split() for l in open('t.tsv', 'r')]
<<<
[['Name', 'Date', 'Color'],
 ['Ray', 'May', 'Gray'],
 ['Alex', 'Apr', 'Green'],
 ['Ann', 'Jun', 'Blue'],
 ['Kev', 'Mar', 'Gold'],
 ['Rob', 'May', 'Black']]
>>> [Entry(*l.split()) for l in open('t.tsv', 'r')]
<<<
[Entry(Name='Name', Date='Date', Color='Color'),
 Entry(Name='Ray', Date='May', Color='Gray'),
 Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green'),
 Entry(Name='Ann', Date='Jun', Color='Blue'),
 Entry(Name='Kev', Date='Mar', Color='Gold'),
 Entry(Name='Rob', Date='May', Color='Black')]    >>> {'fooo':e for e in Entry(*l.split()) for l in open('t.tsv', 'r')}
>>> {e.Name:e for e in list(Entry(*l.split()) for l in open('t.tsv', 'r'))}
<<<
{'Alex': Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green'),
 'Ann': Entry(Name='Ann', Date='Jun', Color='Blue'),
 'Kev': Entry(Name='Kev', Date='Mar', Color='Gold'),
 'Name': Entry(Name='Name', Date='Date', Color='Color'),
 'Ray': Entry(Name='Ray', Date='May', Color='Gray'),
 'Rob': Entry(Name='Rob', Date='May', Color='Black')}
```

I think you are thinking on reading the first row as header names. Python has DictReader - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

```
>>> import csv
>>> for line in csv.DictReader(open('t.tsv')): print line # don't forget to make your file coma-separated. 
{'Date': 'May', 'Color': 'Gray', 'Name': 'Ray'}
{'Date': 'Apr', 'Color': 'Green', 'Name': 'Alex'}
{'Date': 'Jun', 'Color': 'Blue', 'Name': 'Ann'}
{'Date': 'Mar', 'Color': 'Gold', 'Name': 'Kev'}
{'Date': 'May', 'Color': 'Black', 'Name': 'Rob'}
```

or with dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> { line['Name']: line for line in csv.DictReader(open('t.tsv')) }
<<<
{'Alex': {'Color': 'Green', 'Date': 'Apr', 'Name': 'Alex'},
 'Ann': {'Color': 'Blue', 'Date': 'Jun', 'Name': 'Ann'},
 'Kev': {'Color': 'Gold', 'Date': 'Mar', 'Name': 'Kev'},
 'Ray': {'Color': 'Gray', 'Date': 'May', 'Name': 'Ray'},
 'Rob': {'Color': 'Black', 'Date': 'May', 'Name': 'Rob'}}
>>> rows_by_name = { line['Name']: line for line in csv.DictReader(open('t.tsv')) }
>>> rows_by_name['Ann']
<<< {'Color': 'Blue', 'Date': 'Jun', 'Name': 'Ann'}
```

If you want random samples - i suggest first reading a rows into list and then  make selection through randbom module. Or... let's do it with Entry:

```
>>> rows = list(Entry(*l.split()) for l in open('t.tsv', 'r'))
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Ray', Date='May', Color='Gray')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Name', Date='Date', Color='Color')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 1)
<<< [Entry(Name='Alex', Date='Apr', Color='Green')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 3)
<<<
[Entry(Name='Ray', Date='May', Color='Gray'),
 Entry(Name='Kev', Date='Mar', Color='Gold'),
 Entry(Name='Ann', Date='Jun', Color='Blue')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 3)
<<<
[Entry(Name='Ann', Date='Jun', Color='Blue'),
 Entry(Name='Rob', Date='May', Color='Black'),
 Entry(Name='Name', Date='Date', Color='Color')]
>>> random.sample(rows, 3)
<<<
[Entry(Name='Rob', Date='May', Color='Black'),
 Entry(Name='Ann', Date='Jun', Color='Blue'),
 Entry(Name='Kev', Date='Mar', Color='Gold')]
```

but beware, that you can load up your memory too much.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. First issue: you're never *opening* the file located at `file_location`. Thus, when you iterate `for row in spreadsheet:`, you're iterating over the characters of `spreadsheet`, which are the characters of `file_location`, which are the characters of `"C:/Users/..."`. So the first thing you want to do is actually open the file:

```
spreadsheet = open(file_location, 'r')
```

You still have another issue in your loop. When you iterate over a file in a `for` loop, you get back the lines of the file. So, at each iteration, `row` will be a line, e.g. `"Ray  May   Gray"`. When you call `tuple()` on that, you're going to get a tuple that looks like `('R', 'a', 'y', ' ', ' ', 'M', ...)`. What you need to do is construct your tuple by splitting on whitespace:

```
entry = Entry(*row.split())
```

Then, you need to *add* your entry to the dictionary `ss_dict`:

```
ss_dict[entry.Name] = entry
```

Finally, you can read out the value of `ss_dict['Ann']`, but this should be outside your loop - if you do it inside your loop, you may be trying to read the value of `ss_dict['Ann']` before it has been set. All in all, your code should look like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Entry = namedtuple('Entry', 'Name, Date, Color')
file_location = "C:/Users/abriman/Desktop/Book.csv"
ss_dict = {}
spreadsheet = open(file_location, 'r') # <--
for row in spreadsheet:
    entry = Entry(*row.split()) # <--
    ss_dict[entry.Name] = entry # <--
print ss_dict['Ann']
```

---

Incidentally, the reason you're getting your error message there is that when you do `for row in spreadsheet:` with `spreadsheet` being a string, `row` is just a *character*, as I mentioned, and so `tuple(row)` is just a tuple containing one character, and hence is of length 1, so that you're only passing one argument rather than three when you do `*tuple(row)`.

---

All that said, you might want to consider looking at [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), which is part of the standard library, and is precisely designed for reading csv files. It will probably make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: First, you all are awesome! Great responses, and I appreicate the help. For your code, im still getting an error, --------------------{  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print ss_dict['Ann']
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax}
I have also tried indenting it, but nothing.

Comment: @user3726972 Do you have a caret `^` in your code? It looks like it, and that would probably be a syntax error. If the issue is something else, please post another question asking about this new issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
def read_csv_line(line_number, filename):
    with open("filename.csv") as fileobj
        for i, line in enumerate(fileobj):
            if i == (line_number - 1):
                return line
    return None
```

Then you can feed your random number and filename to get a random line.